# Can't create object from VB6 COM DLL using VB6 program

Tags: python, dll, windows-7, vb6

I have a VB6 COM DLL that was developed on a WinXP 32bit system. It works fine on that PC from C#, VB6, and Python applications. I am testing the DLL on another WinXP 32bit system and on Win7 32bit and 64bit. The Python program runs fine on any system. The VB6 program gives 'error 429: ActiveX component can't create object'.

```
Dim foo As testdll.Class1
MsgBox (1)
Set foo = New testdll.Class1
MsgBox (2)
```

The program sees the dll, since the first MsgBox displays fine, but the second one doesn't after trying to create an object. Any ideas?

Comment: The first `MsgBox` does not prove the app sees the dll. `Dim` is no-op, so nothing is tested, no info is fetched from and no code executed from the dll before first `MsgBox`.

Comment: If the dll is not registered, then the first msgbox fails to show.

Comment: Not true, just tested it. Unless you have some other code before first `MagBox` that bombs out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python script is probably creating late bound instances via ProgId.  My guess is you haven't maintained binary compatibility on this DLL so ClassId values have changed, causing problems for early bound client code such as your VB6 client.

Comment: How do I 'maintain binary compatibility' in the DLL? Or how do I late bind it to the VB6 client?

Comment: You might start by reading http://support.microsoft.com/kb/161137 but there is more detail in the documentation.  Late binding is a combination of declaring objects As Object along with using CreateObject() instead of New.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the .dll has a dependency on some other dll, which is absent on the non-development machines. You can check this using [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).

It is no very strange that the first line of code does not raise an error: in this line the Class1 is not initialized, in the second it is. So check the Class_Initialise method for calls to other dll's.

Comment: That may be the case, but why would the DLL work with with Python?